# Why would someone add zero to __STDC_VERSION__?

Tags: c, macros, ansi-c, c-libraries

Looking through `stdarg.h`, I spotted the following:

```
#if !defined(__STRICT_ANSI__) || __STDC_VERSION__ + 0 >= 199900L
#define va_copy(d,s)    __builtin_va_copy(d,s)
#endif
```

Is there a purpose to adding 0 in the expression?

Comment: `stdarg.h` from which toolchain or system ?

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers will just ignore this. It may be some left over code from some previous implementation or it may be something that was done to convince a specific compiler to treat this however the programmer intended.